# How to start python Eel in any available browser of user system?

Tags: python, eel

I am trying to create a windows based application using eel. I want it to start in any available browser in the system of the user. How can I do it ? ( consider that user have not installed chrome in his system )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in `mode='default'` to the `eel.start` function, and it will try to open the system's default browser. Something like this:

```py
eel.start('index.html', mode='default')
```

In this case, behind-the-scenes Eel will be proxying the open request to Python's [webbrowser.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) function, so it's best to check there if you want to know the logic being used. Or you can look at the Python source file for `webbrowser.py` on your machine... on Windows it would be located somewhere like: `C:\Python39\Lib\webbrowser.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late for you, I had the same problem. So to resolve it you have open your folder with code source of eel and open **init**.py and change browser option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).